# Conjugacy Classes of $D_{12}$

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to find the conjugacy classes of the Dihedral group $D_{12}=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5,b,ba,ba^2,ba^3,ba^4,ba^5\}$

where $a^6=b^2=e$ and $ab=ba^5$.
I know that one of the conjugacy classes will be $C_e=\{e\}$ but I don't understand how you find the others. All help appreciated.

Comment: Do you use $D_{12}$ is the symmetry of the hexagon or $12$-gon?

Comment: The dihedral group, $D_{12}=\{e, a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5, b, ba, ba^2, ba^3, ba^4, ba^5\}$  


$a^6=b^2=e$ and $ab=ba^5$

Comment: I dont understand the notation used in that version, could you explain it in a simpler way?

Comment: what notation do you not know? It looks like a pretty bare-boned explanation in the OP

Comment: I am fairly new to conjugacy classes so i need it explained in words more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is the Dihedral group?**

The dihedral group $D_{2n}$ consists of symmetries of some $n$-gon. The elements are thus some combination of rotations and reflections. In particular, the group $D_{12}$ is the group of symmetries for a hexagon. The group operation is the composition of two transformations that leave the hexagon fixed. For example, $a$ is a rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{6}$, or a one sixth turn. Thus, $a^{k}$ is a $\frac{2 \pi k}{6}$ turn, which is why $a^6=e$. Similarly, pick some line that goes through two vertices of the hexagon and call the reflection about it $b$. Then reflecting twice is $b^2$, which is just identity, since we have done nothing to the hexagon. Reflections about other lines can be expressed by first rotating, and then reflecting our hexagon. Thus, all reflections are given by $ba^{k}$ for $0 \leq k  \leq 5$. So, we have $6$ reflections and $6$ rotations, which are all symmetries, giving us a group of order $12$. Note that "inverses" for rotation are just rotating in the opposite direction. In particular, $a^{-1}$ is a rotation clockwise, which is the same thing as $a^5$ (draw a picture.) Finally, note that reflecting, then rotating, and reflecting back is the same thing as rotating once in the clockwise (backward) direction, so $bab=a^{-1}$. A different way of writing this is:
$$D_{12}:= \langle a,b \mid a^6=e=b^2,\,\, bab=a^{-1} \rangle$$

**What is Conjugacy?**

The basic heuristic for conjugacy is that two elements are conjugate if they have the same "type" in the sense that for example, reflecting about two different lines can often be seen as being "of the same type," while rotating once is sincerely different from rotating this twice. The group theoretic way of making this intuition precise is as follows:

\textbf{definition:} $a \in G$ is conjugate to $b \in G$ if there exists some $g \in G$ so that $a=gbg^{-1}$. If we interpret groups as symmetries of some object, this says there is some symmetry $g$ so that doing it, applying $b$ and undoing $g$ is the same thing as doing $a$.

The main trouble with applying this intuition for an even $n$-gon, is that there are extra axes of symmetry that go through two sides of a polygon, so conjugacy classes of reflections break into essentially two different types. Rotations, however will still only be conjugate to their inverses

---

**Claim:** The conjugacy classes for $D_{12}$ are
$$\{e\}, \{a^{3}\},\{a^{\pm 1}\}, \{a^{\pm 2}\}$$
$$\{a^2 b,b,a^{4}b\}$$
$$\{ab,a^{3}b,a^{5}b\}$$

where odd $a$ reflections correspond to reflections about a line that goes through two sides, and even $a$ reflections go through two vertices.

To see this in a more algebraic way:

Conjugating a rotation: $(a^ib)(a^k)(a^ib)^{-1}=a^ib(a^k)ba^{-i}=a^{-k}$, and similarly, since rotations commute with rotations, we see that conjugating by a rotation is again just a rotation.

You can do similar things for conjugating a reflection, just using the equations provided by the presentation of the group I have in the first section.

---

I found a very detailed reference [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/%7Ekconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral.pdf), that goes through the intuition with all the proofs and many pictures.

Comment: The last class ${ab,a^5b}$ should include $a^3b$ since $a^3b=(a^4b)(a^5b)(a^4b)^{-1}$.